# Javascript or JQuery for showing an image when URL entered into textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone have an example of Javascript or JQuery, that will automatically show an image, based on a URL entered into a text box on an html page?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you coded till now for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has assumptions about the element IDs, but does what you ask...

```
$(function() {
  $("#textbox").on("change", function() {
    $("#image").prop("src", $(this).val());
  });
});
```

It assumes that you have an input with an ID of `textbox` and an image with an ID of `image`.  Once you finish typing in the textbox and leave it, the image will load the URL you entered (as long as it's a valid image).

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this: ([wokring codepan](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mkcrL))

```
$(function(){
    $('input').blur(function(){
        $('#container').html('<img alt="" src="'+$(this).val()+'">');
    });
})
```

This will add the image to the page the second you leave the input (`blur` event). You can change it to `keyup` if you like.